# Safari reponsive design mode is super zoomed out and media queries fail to fix it

Tags: html, css

I am on the last page of my website that I am adjusting to an iPhone 8.  However, the safari responsive design mode displays a super zoomed-out view of the page.  When trying to adjust the contents using media queries nothing will work.

This is the code for that specific media query:

```
    @media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 812px) {
```

and so on.

Here is an image:

[Image of the responsive design mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgrOe.jpg)

Comment: Have you set the viewport for the page?

Comment: @FluffyKitten Yes I did.  In the html it is:

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />